# Issue reading barcode content in EMDK Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk, zebra-scanners

In my barcode contains a Norwegian character (Ålesund). But while scanning it on the Zebra device I am not getting the letter (Å) instead I am getting something like this (�lesund).

The configuration that I am following the app is,

```
 if (null != _mScanner)
            {
                if (_mScanner.IsEnabled && !_mScanner.IsReadPending)
                {
                    //EMDK: Configure the scanner settings
                    var config = _mScanner.GetConfig();
                    if (null != config)
                    {
                        config.ScanParams.DecodeLEDFeedback = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Code39.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Code93.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Code128.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Ean8.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Pdf417.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Enabled = true;
                        _mScanner.SetConfig(config);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can anyone please help me to identify what exactly I am missing in the config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the below reader param. That will solve your issue.

```
config.ReaderParams.ReaderSpecific.ImagerSpecific.CharacterSetSelection = ScannerConfig.CharacterSet.Iso88591;
```